# Excel formula: how to sum total time between different time intervals based on a time condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```html
A                                  B
Departure Date               Arrival date 
4/9/18 22:40              5/17/18 14:10
8/5/18 18:20              8/22/18 6:00
9/24/18 22:20              10/10/18 6:00
10/22/18 14:00              11/7/18 6:10
12/3/18 22:25              12/19/18 6:00
1/16/19 0:00              1/30/19 0:00
```

I need some help please. I have to calculate the total travel days for our employees for a specific period of time. I have columns A and B (all are date and time). Column A is the Departure Date, Column B is the Arrival Date.

---

Question: which is the Total number of travel days between:5/10/2018 and 12/10/2018?

Comment: How about in Col C calculating the duration of each trip, then iusing countifs() to sum the relevant ones matching the date range.

Comment: The problem is that for the beginning of the date range and for the end I only need to sum partial duration. For example, if in A1 I have 05/10/2018 and B1 05/20/2018, then I only need 3 days from this duration, the ones between 05/17/2018 and 05/20/2018, based on my condition above.

Comment: Then do a calculation for that - ie start time to end-limit or end time after start-limit.

Comment: @ Solar Mike: I am sorry, I do not know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you may need to edit it to match your needs though...

```
IF(AND(A4>=$A$1,B4<=$B$1),B4-A4,IF(AND(A4<=A$1,B4<=$B$1),B4-$A$1,IF(AND(A4>=A$1,B4>=$B$1),$B$1-A4)))
```

See:
[image]

Comment: Suggest adding a test for no overlap (which may produce a negative result), unless the data is such that there is always an overlap. Although a sumif on column C which includes only positive values will probably be OK.

Comment: @Tom Sharpe: your comment is correct. What I used was a Max ( result, zero) function, which also does the job.